# Maximum amount of users in a Skype (Free) Group Video chat

Tags: video, skype, streaming, bandwidth, conferencing

A group of users in my office would like to use Skype for some regular meetings when they are out of the office. Is there a hard limit to how many users can be in a group video call with the Basic (not Premium) version of Skype?

None of the information on Skype's website is 100% clear.

> https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10613/what-do-i-need-to-make-a-group-video-call
>
> lists what hardware specifications are recommended for 3, 5 or 7 user group video chats

---

> https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10872/i-have-a-problem-with-my-group-video-call?q=maximum+users+is+video+call
>
> mentions a possible issue when a tenth user enters a group video call

---

> http://www.skype.com/en/legal/gvc-fair-usage/
>
> describes Skype's fair use policy for am ount of time spent on calls

---

> http://www.skype.com/en/business/
>
> states that the business version can have up to 250 users in a group video conference

none of what I'm finding shows a hard number for how many users can be in a Skype group video conference while using the free version.

Does anyone have any more information? It's looking like it may be a soft limit based on each users system hardware and the bandwidth of all the users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Skype](https://www.skype.com/en/features/calling-and-instant-messaging/) features page, the limit is now 50.

> Skype to Skype calling lets you make free calls online for up to 50 people.

Answer (score 3):

Now the limit was raised to 50.

[Free conference calls and group video chat](https://www.skype.com/en/features/group-calls/)